# Django cannot delete custom field class; makemigrations throws AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

**Lead-up:**

I subclassed `django.db.models.fields.CharField`. Then used that custom field called `myapp.models.QueryStringField` in a model and made my migrations and migrated successfully. Then I changed my mind and decided to replace it with a normal `CharField` in my model, which I did (again with successfull migration).

**Problem:**

When I then deleted the `QueryStringField` class entirely from `myapp.models` and did `makemigrations`, it threw the following error (last lines shown here):

```py
File "C:\...\migrations\00....py", line 17, in Migration
    field=myapp.models.QueryStringField(max_length=255),
AttributeError: module 'myapp.models' has no attribute 'QueryStringField'
```

What can I do to fix this? I understand that this is technically correct, since the migration references a class that is not present, but surely this can be solved somehow. I am a little nervous about just deleting migration files.

Comment: You can not easily delete that field, since it is referenced by the migration files. Probably it might work if you remove the parts in your migration file where the field is altered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not just delete a field class, that class is *referenced* by the migration files.

You should change the migration files where the `QueryStringField` is involved. You can inspect the migration where you changed the field, and remove that part of the migration, so:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('someapp', '1234_some_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # migrations.AlterField(
        #     model_name='mymodel',
        #     name='myfield',
        #     field=models.QueryStringField(
        #         # ...
        #     ),
        # ),
    ]
```

as well as in the migration where you change it back:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('someapp', '5678_some_other_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # migrations.AlterField(
        #     model_name='mymodel',
        #     name='myfield',
        #     field=models.CharField(
        #         # ...
        #     ),
        # ),
    ]
```

After you removed these changes (and all changes that thus work with the `QueryStringField`), you can safely remove it.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. And more importantly, I now understand the way the migrations work a little better. I suppose I could have removed and edited some of the files entirely, but this is a safer solution.